# Devise use an alternative to password

Tags: authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently working on a project that needs a kinda special authentication. I got a list of users which includes their membership number and their firstname and lastname.

I'm using devise for authentication and I'd like to authenticate with that number plus a combination of their first and lastname like:

```
01272726
Bruce Wayne
```

I've switched from the email authentication to the uuid (membership number) but I can't figure out how I could replace the password with the name.

I thought about generating the password for them when uploading the users to the database but idk how to encrypt it. :/

I hope somebody can help me out. Thank you!

Comment: Is the membership number secret like a password? Do you save the membership number in a file (or DB)?

Comment: @zaph yea it's secret. I got a csv with single columns for first name, lastname and the number

Comment: If the membership number is going to be used as a password, the secret login credential, it must not be saved either as plain text or encrypted in any file. Do not encrypt passwords, if encrypterd when the attacker gets the CSV file he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: As I was reading your comment I was thinking about just using the number as the actual password and creating the users with User.create(...., password: number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the password column as my 'alternative'. When importing the users I was just using the password column for the unique member number instead of using another column.